# problems with IOS storage

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

Sorry for my english. I have a problem with a storage and Apple rejected my app. I use a sqlite db in my app and copy it from bundle because I need update records in a db. There is many information about this but all it not working for me!

I tryed to use `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` with directories `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`, `library/caches` and another, but it's not working and I see my app in storage with size of db, if I not copy my db I dont see my app in storage, but I need a copy.

What I have to do?

I use iOs9 , xCode 7:

```
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_words"];
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_words"];
NSURL *applicationSupportDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]     URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                                                     inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                                   appropriateForURL:nil
                                                                      create:YES
                                                                       error:&error];

NSURL *referenceFolder = [applicationSupportDirectory     URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Reference" isDirectory:YES];

success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[referenceFolder path]
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error]

success = [referenceFolder setResourceValue:@YES forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

if(!success){
    NSLog(@"KCDM: Error excluding %@ from backup %@", referenceFolder, error);
}


NSString * writableDBPath = [referenceFolder.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_words"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

return writableDBPath;
```

Comment: please add Apple rejection description,

Comment: 2.23 Details On launch and content download, your app stores 66.91 MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data

Comment: and i also see this 67 mb in storage, but i dont have any ideas why?

Comment: Please see my answer..it's not related to storage/size but related to backup policy

Answer (score 1):

Since On launch and content download are not started by user "user generated data" but by your application on lunch, Apple want to know about the "do not back up" policy(to iCloud) to apply on this downloaded data and also if this data can be recreated ? /or should remain on device, even in low storage situations. all this situations are well explained [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html)

So providing a policy for you app-launch-downloaded-data will resolve your issue...

in your case you may need only to skipBackup for applicationSupportDirectory, so in `appDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  add skip backups:

```
//[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[AppDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory]]];

    //[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[AppDelegate applicationLibraryDirectory]]];

    //[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[AppDelegate applicationTemporaryDirectory]]];

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[AppDelegate applicationSupportDirectory]]];
```

> Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this
>   attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in
>   low storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because
>   customers expect it to be available during offline use.

and add this methods:

```
       - (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
        {
            assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                          forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
            if(!success){
                NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
            }
            return success;
        }

        + (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
            return basePath;
        }

        + (NSString *) applicationLibraryDirectory
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
            return basePath;
        }

        + (NSString *) applicationTemporaryDirectory
        {
            return NSTemporaryDirectory();
        }




       + (NSString *) applicationSupportDirectory  //review this to get the right basePath
     {
    // return basePath to applicationSupportDirectory
      //NSURL *applicationSupportDirectory = [[NSFileManager 
     // defaultManager] 
     //URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory 
     // inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES 
     // error:&error];

     //OR use
     // NSString *appSupportDir =  
  //[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, 
    // NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    //appSupportDir = [appSupportDir 
    //   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppDirectory"];
    //return [NSURL URLWithString:appSupportDir];
   }
```

Comment: About iCloud, i dont now all, but its from  apple "To check how much data your app is storing:

    - Install and launch your app
    - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage
    - Select your device
    - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
    - Check your app's storage" and in this case i see 67mb (

Comment: be sure to get the right path to your basePath to applicationSupportDirectory

Comment: thanks for help,  i think that i saw wrong menu, not icloud , because it was in Russian on my phone and in this way i tryed to resolve resolved problem)
in Russian interface this "Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage - Select your device" not correct path it seems like a path to local storage and i saw my 67 mb, but in icloud never was 67!! this is another question i saw this question on forums apple write size different , than people see, but now it doesnt matter for me , my problem is resolved